# inotify fails to pick up changes in innodb .ibd files

Tags: mysql, linux, database, innodb

I use inotify to monitor changes to mysql data files, and the storage engine is InnoDB. inotify will consistently fail to capture any events when actually the data in the InnoDB .IBD files are updated. However, when I convert the storage of the same tables to MyISAM storage engine, everything works like a charm.

Anything thoughts on what is going on?

Comment: Can you post an example showing how you are using inotify?

Comment: $ inotifywatch -v -t 60 -r /var/lib/mysql/foo.ibd

. . .

Comment: I set innodb_file_per_table=1, and actually monitor a .ibd file for each table. The time stamp of the .ibd file has changed and the SHA1 hash of the .ibd file has also changed, even though the file size has not changed. However, inotify will not pick it up

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB does not immediately write to the tablespace; this way, it can be faster.  It does write to logs so that it is ACID.

You are asking for something that MySQL is not able to provide, and should not be expected to provide.

However, If you turn on the binlog and monitor it, you can capture all modifications to all tables.  Perhaps a combination of `inotify` and `tail -f binlog...` would work for you?  (Note: the name of the binlog file will change periodically.)

Comment: Thanks Rick James

Comment: Thanks Rick James, what i want to is, i want to create a data warehouse in elastic search and wants to keep  this data in mysql to always be in sync with that in elastic search in real time.So, what i want to do is, use Inotify to pick up all these changes in the .ibd files , but with MyISAM,  Inotify does pick these changes  in the .MYD files, but with Innodb, inotify don't pick these changes.I want  Inotify to pick these changes in the Innodb.ibd files otherwise can you propose a way to replicate data into elastic search.Thanks.

Comment: Some 3rd party packages monitor the binlog to capture changes.  I am not familiar with the details.  Eg:  Orchestrator; gh-ost.

Comment: Thanks Rick James, do you know of any monitoring tool  use to  monitor innodb .ibd files other than inotify???.